# Blender crashes on startup, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: exception, crash, blender

I've just downloaded Blender 2.75a, and all it does is bring up a console window that says "Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

The console window will not close, will not exit with task manager, and when I try to end its process it says Access is Denied. So I have a permanent broken blender on my desktop until I restart.

How do I make blender run?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed the problem. I went to this page http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/ and I downloaded the 2.76 experimental version win64 from the zip folder. You can downlad it directly from this link if you have win64: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/blender-2.76-testbuild1-win64.zip

I hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

On my computer this error was caused by the video card driver, in particular the Intel GMA 4500 graphics driver that Windows 8.1 will automatically (re-)install with Windows update. This video card is often found in older laptops with Core 2 Duo processors.

In previous tests I found out that the driver version that Microsoft provides through Windows update does include the required OpenGL version for some games and graphics applications.

I solved this problem by downloading and modifying (according to [this tutorial](http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10072)) Intel GMA 4500 driver version 15.17.19.64.2869 (file name `Win7Vista_64_151719.exe`) so that I can install it on Windows 8.1. But keep in mind that this can cause some graphical artifacts and glitches that you would normally not see.